# ExpressJS + Sequelize er_bad_field_error: Unknown column in fieldlist

Tags: node.js, express, database-schema, sequelize.js

Using the following model file in conjunction with Sequelize, this code runs without error and allows me to perform an insert:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

var User = sequelize.define('User', 
    {
        title: DataTypes.STRING,
        name: DataTypes.STRING,
        email: DataTypes.STRING,
        username: DataTypes.STRING,
        hashedPassword: DataTypes.STRING,
        provider: DataTypes.STRING,
        salt: DataTypes.STRING, 
        facebookUserId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        twitterUserId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        twitterKey: DataTypes.STRING,
        twitterSecret: DataTypes.STRING,
        github: DataTypes.STRING,
        openID: DataTypes.STRING
    },
...
)
```

However, when I try to manually add my own fields of interest, i.e. adding a ZIP code field as below:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

var User = sequelize.define('User', 
    {
        title: DataTypes.STRING,
        name: DataTypes.STRING,
        email: DataTypes.STRING,
        username: DataTypes.STRING,
        hashedPassword: DataTypes.STRING,
        provider: DataTypes.STRING,
        salt: DataTypes.STRING, 
        facebookUserId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        twitterUserId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        twitterKey: DataTypes.STRING,
        twitterSecret: DataTypes.STRING,
        github: DataTypes.STRING,
        openID: DataTypes.STRING,
        ZIP: DataTypes.INT
    },
```

the following error propagates:

```
 SequelizeDatabaseError: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'title' in 'field list'
```

Why am I not allowed to add fields within the models to be able to access them from the controller?

Comment: Are you syncing your model with database ? , make sure u are doing it , about your ZIP field there is no datatype INT  , there is INTEGER  , http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/datatypes/#integer

Comment: The syncing of the model with database occurs after an insert, correct? Also, I changed the ZIP type to INTEGER and the exact same error was propagated

Comment: You have to sync your model schema , this will change your table in database , so if u could check that there is a ZIP column in your table its all ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe sequelize/SQL is confused because of an existing row in an old table. Have you tried deleting any existing tables in the db if you've already made some? As it was said already, syncing the db is important, but also set "force" to true so that you wipe the old tables (ONLY DO THIS IF YOUR DB ISN'T IN PRODUCTION!). It's in the docs: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/1.7.0/articles/getting-started/

It worked for me.

```
sequelize 
.sync({ force: true })
.then(function(err) {
    console.log('It worked!');
  }, function (err) { 
         console.log('An error occurred while creating the table:', err);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `sync({ force: true })` will recreate the table while deleting all entries that is if you have the db in production. You can try using the same but with an alter option `sync({ alter: true })`. It will try and update the new or remove the old values without much harm. I would try it first in dev mode before pushing to production.